# ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Tags: python, pip, installation

I try to install `virtualenvwrapper-win` module,and do:

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper-win"
```

It showed the error in the last line:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

I've completely reinstalled python and updated to latest versions and checked version 64 - bit.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the installation of gdown package from pip.

[screenshot of the error I was getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXZQo.png)

But then, I figured out that the actual problem was with my **antivirus**. Try the following steps -

1. Open terminal with admin access.
2. Try disabling your antivirus.
3. Check Internet connection.
4. Try restarting your computer.

Any of the above measures should work. Mine had the problem with the antivirus.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pip3 install virtualenvwrapper-win`

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: "Am using Windows 10"

Comment: After Installing too it shows: OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor , while running "mkvirtualenv test" , yet the environment gets created and i cannot activate it .

Answer (score 0):

EnvError and OSerror are brought back when python is not involved, so it is our OS that must present inconsistencies for it (in the processes for example) even if the message returned by python is earlier vague. Here's what I did for me. I just downloaded the iso of my OS, ran it to redo my system. With the option to keep my programs installed I always had the same python error so I had to separate myself from all my installed programs except my drivers and my personal files (music, videos, etc.) managed automatically by this repair mode. If not there's also the Windows Dism tool that could help, well I think, I didn't manage to use it because of its error codes that I found interminable. it allows you to repair windows system files you could know more about it and the method I used on their official website and on other third party sites. When has the cause of this problem, I think it's due to a malware that is installed on your system and that modifies the behavior of your OS, because I had unfortunately installed one on my pc the day the python error appeared. I hope I have helped. My OS is Win 8.1